# Iframe does not load all kml layers

Tags: iframe, browser, joomla, kml

I have a JOOMLA! website where a iframe loads a total of 9 kml files. It worked fine, when I established it in 2022. But lately, I noticed that one of the kml files (the largest one, not the last one in the code) does not load any more. It also doesn't show up in the layer menu, where you can select and unselect each layer.

I've tested it with Firefox, Chrome and Edge, all have the same issue. I wonder whether it might be a browser problem.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Try making the file smaller, perhaps their is new size limit

Comment: I divided the large file into three smaller ones of each 4MB. That did the trick. Thanks for your reply.